# check whether the list of strings contains all characters of another string -Python

Tags: python, substring

```
S = ['cat','tor','tutorial','item','aba','tori']  
T = "oti"


for item in S:
    for i in item:
        if i in T:
            print(item)
```

I want to get 'tori' and 'tutorial' because those are the 2 words that contain `o`, `t`, `i`. The code above will print everything from the list. Using find() is not an option because there is no match.

Will using match be a good option here? I could use some hint here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) for membership testing.

```
>>> 
>>> T = 'oti'
>>> S = ['cat','tor','tutorial','item','aba','tori']
>>> t = set(T)
>>> t
{'o', 't', 'i'}
>>> for thing in S:
...     if t.issubset(thing):
            print(thing)


tutorial
tori
>>>
```

---

This won't work if there are duplicate characters.

```
>>> q = set('otti')
>>> for thing in S:
...     if q.issubset(thing):
            print(thing)


tutorial
tori
>>>
```

---

Using `all`

```
>>> 
>>> for thing in S:
...     if all(c in thing for c in T):
            print(thing)


tutorial
tori
>>>
```